# Make a Messagebox display a variable

Tags: c#, variables, messagebox

I want a `MessageBox` to display an `int` variable, can anybody help?

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the [MessageBox.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598674%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method

```
int num = 0;
MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use string formatting with the message box:

```
int courseId = 0;

DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Print Course No {0} ?", courseId), "Print Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Answer (score 1):

jb's answer is correct, if you need some more information MSDN has full documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984357(v=vs.71).aspx

For simple library matters, MSDN nearly always has excellent, easy to understand documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy. Don't get confused and write `int test = 1;`, then `MessageBox.Show("test:" + 1)`, because then if `test`'s value changes, that will just print `1` instead of `test`'s new value `2`.

Example:

```
int test = 1;
test = test + 1;
MessageBox.Show(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to achieve this, see this example:

```
int a=1;
MessageBox.Show(a+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:
int test = 0;
messagebox.show(Convert.ToString(test));

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever you post a code fragment please use the code formatting tools. Also please provide explanation as well not just code.